# How to create a CSV file with normalized data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with variables which I want to normalize using Z score method in order to perform some machine learning algorithms.
I have wrote this code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\....csv")
data.head()

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data)
```

How can I create a csv file with the normalized columns so I can check everything is correct? Or how can I do something like I did with `data.head()` but with the normalized dataset so I can check? Is this code correct?

Comment: Normalized data that happens to be in a DB is not what "DB normalization" is about.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful: you should scale your data after splitting, not before. For example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

I would not save the transformed data anywhere. In fact, you will usually want to put the scaling function in a pipeline, which is 'safer' than scaling it ahead of time because it enables, for example, folded cross validation

Remember you can always check a variable in the Python REPL or a notebook by just typing its name and executing. So you can look at `X_train_scaled` without putting it in a DataFrame or writing a CSV.

Comment: I've read from Santiago that it's better to scale data before splitting, and use the training scaling on the test data.  You don't want the test data to leak into the training data in any way.

Comment: @duffymo You should split before scaling to avoid leakage. Then you can fit the scaler to the training split only. If you scale before splitting, then the scaler has seen too much, so to speak.

Comment: Of course.  I had it exactly backwards.  You said it correctly, but I misunderstood what you meant.  Need more coffee.

Comment: @MattHall: Does this code apply data normalization also to categorical variables, or only to continous? Because I have a dataset with both categorical and continous variables, and I read that the standardization should only be performed on continous.

Comment: It applies to any data you give it. Unless the feature is ordinal, you should certainly not scale it this way but instead you probably want to dummy encode it. And no need to wonder with Python: you can run it yourself on different inputs to see exactly what it does.

Comment: After running this code, I get: NameError: name 'X' is not defined

Comment: You need to make `X` and `y`. `X` is like `features = ['col 1', 'col 2']; X = df[features]` and `y` is like `df['target']` (depending on what your DataFrame columns are called).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create another column containing the scaled values

```
data['scaled'] = scaled
```

It will create new column then you can simply compare the values

Comment: And afterwards I write: scaled.head() to see, correct?

Comment: no you just `data.head()` and you will see new column is displayed along with your original data

Comment: I think you mean `data['scaled'] = scaled`?

Comment: The code does not work.

Comment: @user19745561 Generic comments like " Dont work" are not useful for people to help you. You need to be specific on what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

i do this and works good:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\....csv")

tf_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)

mean = data.mean()
stddev = data.std()

def normalize(features):
    return (features - mean) / stddev

normalized_data = tf_data.map(normalize)

normalized_data_iter = normalized_data.as_numpy_iterator()
normalized_df = pd.DataFrame(list(normalized_data_iter), columns=data.columns)

print(normalized_df.head())

normalized_df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\...._normalized.csv", index=False)
```